# Append to np.array in pd.DataFrame cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have an existing `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["a", "b", "c"],
                  "y": [7, 8, 9],
                  "value": [np.array([2, 3]), np.array([3, 4, 5]), np.array([4, 5, 6])]},
                 index=[0, 0, 0])

d
#>    x  y      value
#> 0  a  7     [2, 3]
#> 0  b  8  [3, 4, 5]
#> 0  c  9  [4, 5, 6]
```

Now let's say I want to append a `9` to the `value` where `x=="b"`.  I can create the replacement array simply enough:

```
ix = d['x'] == "b"
np.append(d.loc[ix, "value"].iloc[0], 9)
#> array([3, 4, 5, 9])
```

But the most obvious solutions for inserting into the `DataFrame` don't seem to work:

```
d[ix, 'value'] = np.append(d.loc[ix, "value"].iloc[0], 9)
#> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3163, in __setitem__
#>     self._set_item(key, value)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3242, in _set_item
#>     value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3899, in _sanitize_column
#>     value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 752, in sanitize_index
#>     "Length of values "
#> ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (3)

d.loc[ix, 'value'] = np.append(d.loc[ix, "value"].iloc[0], 9)
#> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 692, in __setitem__
#>     iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1635, in _setitem_with_indexer
#>     self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1689, in _setitem_with_indexer_split_path
#>     "Must have equal len keys and value "
#> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

d.loc[ix]['value'] = np.append(d.loc[ix, "value"].iloc[0], 9)
#> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3163, in __setitem__
#>     self._set_item(key, value)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3242, in _set_item
#>     value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3899, in _sanitize_column
#>     value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 752, in sanitize_index
#>     "Length of values "
#> ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (1)


# No error, but doesn't have any effect either:
d.loc[ix, 'value'].iloc[0] = np.append(d.loc[ix, "value"].iloc[0], 9)
d
#>    x  y      value
#> 0  a  7     [2, 3]
#> 0  b  8  [3, 4, 5]
#> 0  c  9  [4, 5, 6]
```

The only thing I've figured out is to extract the row, modify the row, and then stick the row back in:

```
row = d.loc[ix]

# Seems like it should work, but doesn't:
row['value'] = np.append(d.loc[ix, "value"].iloc[0], 9)
#> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3163, in __setitem__
#>     self._set_item(key, value)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3242, in _set_item
#>     value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3899, in _sanitize_column
#>     value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
#>   File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 752, in sanitize_index
#>     "Length of values "
#> ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (1)


# Wrap it in a list for no good reason I can figure out - I get a warning, but hey, it works...
row['value'] = [np.append(d.loc[ix, "value"].iloc[0], 9)]
#> __main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
#> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
#> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
#> 
#> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

d.loc[ix] = row
d
#>    x  y         value
#> 0  a  7        [2, 3]
#> 0  b  8  [3, 4, 5, 9]
#> 0  c  9     [4, 5, 6]
```

What's a better way?

Here are my versions:

```
sys.version
#> '3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) \n[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]'

pd.__version__
#> '1.2.3'

np.__version__
#> '1.20.2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, pandas doesn't do well with array/list inputs (because it's not really built for that and it is generally advised that you DO NOT do this, [see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373714/generic-dont-do-it-answer)). However, since the question was asked, this is how I've solved it:

```
d.loc[ix, 'value'] = pd.Series([np.append(d.loc[ix, "value"].iloc[0], 9)])
```

Because of the error you got in your first attempt (`ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (3)`), pandas does not accept np.array assignments because it interprets it as values that are to be allocated to a range of indices. Therefore, you have to convert it away from numpy to a pandas series so that it doesn't interpret it this way and can handle the internal data innately.

Comment: Thanks - am I understanding correctly that once the assignment to the cell is made, the cell contains the extracted vanilla numpy array rather than a `pd.Series` object?

Comment: Yes, you can check by just extracting the new 'value' and checking its type: `type(d.loc[ix,'value'][0])`